# 4x4 Hermitian matrix transformation under SU(4)

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Consider a $4\times4$ Hermitian matrix, we can expand by the basis which is the set of identity and the generators of SU(4). Then we get a real vector. After acting an element of SU(4), we get another Hermitian operator, which corresponds to a different vector. Can we relate the old and new vector by this SU(4) matrix? (I am thinking about the case of $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix under SU(2), which is interpreted as a SO(3) rotation, not sure whether it is possible to generalize this property)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For SU(2) ~ SO(3) we call this operation an adjoint rotation.
That is, for the three generators of $\mathfrak su(2)$, The Pauli vector
$\vec a\cdot \vec\sigma$ maps to $[\vec b\cdot \vec\sigma, \vec a\cdot \vec\sigma]=2i (\vec a\times \vec b )\cdot \vec \sigma$, the increment under an infinitesimal rotation by angle/axis $\vec b$, an *ajoint action*! For a full rotation, $\vec a\cdot \vec\sigma \mapsto e^{i\vec b\cdot \vec\sigma}~\vec a\cdot \vec\sigma ~e^{-i\vec a\cdot \vec\sigma}   $.

Likewise, the  $\mathfrak su(4)$ Lie algebra,
$$
[T_i,T_j]=if^k_{ij} T_k 
$$
involves the 15-dimensional vectors $A^i$, so that (summation over repeated indices),
$$
A^iT_i \mapsto [A^iT_i,B^jT_j]=i (A^i f^k_{ij} B^j) T_k
$$
again under  action by an adjoint $\mathfrak su(4)$-"rotation" by and angle/axis $B^jT_j$.

All these statements may be suitably exponentiated to the group level, from the algebra level here.